# if $A$ is Real skew Symmetric Matrix Then Prove that $I-A$ is Non singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

if $A$ is Real skew Symmetric Matrix Then Prove that $I-A$ is Non singular.

i have taken $2 \times 2$ matrix and proved it but is there a formal way to prove it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Given any vector $x$, we have
$$ x^T(I-A)x = \lVert x \rVert^2 - x^TAx. $$
But since this is a scalar, $x^TAx = (x^TAx)^T = x^TA^Tx = -x^TAx $, because $A$ is skew-symmetric, so $x^TAx=0$ and thus $x^T(I-A)x = \lVert x \rVert^2 > 0$ provided that $x \neq 0$. Hence $\ker{(I-A)} = \{0\}$, which is the same as $I-A$ being nonsingular.

Comment: sir i do not know what is kernel , can you be more specific

Comment: The kernel of a matrix is the set of vectors that it sends to $0$. If a matrix $M$ is singular, its determinant is zero, so one of $M$'s eigenvalues is zero, so there is a nonzero vector $v$ so that $Mv=0$, and hence the kernel contains a nonzero vector.

Comment: Ok so what i understood is if $x^T(I-A)x=\left \| x \right \|^2$ and if we assume $x$ is non null vector. Then $I-A$ cannot be singular since when $I-A$ is singular there exists non zero vector $x$ such that $(I-A)x=0$ since rows of $I-A$ are Linearly dependent. Then $x^T(I-A)x=x^T0=0$ hence $ \left \| x \right \|^2=0$ $\implies$ $x=0$ which is a contradiction, hence $I-A$ is Non singular.

Comment: But what if when $x$ is zero vector?

Comment: The zero vector always maps to zero, so it doesn't tell you anything either way. The point is that the result holds for *all* nonzero $x$, so there's no nonzero $x$ in the kernel.